# Package Execution fails on SSISDB with Error "Unable to create the type with the name DynamicsCRM"

Tags: ssis, dynamics-crm-365, kingswaysoft, azure-data-factory

I am facing issue in executing from packages from Azure-Integration Runtime. It was working fine 3 months ago but now I am getting this error

["Unable to create the type with name Dynamics CRM"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nd7r.png)

I have reinstalled all the software related to Kingswaysoft but still the issue persists.

Comment: This is an installation issue, you would want to check if the main.cmd file contains the line that installs our Dynamics365 toolkit. Also, after starting your IR, you should be able to find the log files in your blob container which contains the details about the installation. If you still have trouble, please reach out to our support channel.

Comment: main.cmd file already contains the line to install Dynamics365 toolkit